# can't find center to zoom into for google maps markerclusterer

Tags: google-maps, zooming, markerclusterer

This may have a very simple solution, but I am having trouble with it. I have a simple markerclusterer. It clusters two points:
https://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/dev/test.php

I also have it as a fiddle, but even though I copied my code exactly, the fiddle isn't working:
https://jsfiddle.net/LNMSchneiderman/zk9y1g0j/3/

The default behavior when you click the markerclusterer has it zooming in so tight that you can't see any street names or any landmarks. I would like it to not zoom in so tightly. I've gotten it to adjust the zoom, but now I can't get it to center on the cluster. Can anyone help?

The relevant code is:

```
var markerClusterer  = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m', gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15
                    }); //setting maxZoom doesn't fix this problem
                    
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer , 'clusterclick', function(cluster){
    if (markerClusterer.isZoomOnClick()) {
        //map.setCenter(cluster.latlng);//"cannot read properties of undefined"
        map.panTo(markerClusterer.getCenter()); //error: not a function
        this.map.setZoom(markerClusterer.getMaxZoom()+1); //works, but doesn't center on the cluster
    }

                        
});
```

Comment: You did *not* copy the code exactly when creating your jsFiddle... it misses the opening function declaration ;-)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius: You are right :)! I added the opening function declaration...but the fiddle still shows an error :(.

Comment: You did remember to add the jQuery, Google Maps & the markercluster scripts to the fiddle? Seems to work OK [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/bu2hqxpr/12/)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius: I did add them. At least it works somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is sort of inexact, but what I did was this:

```
var markerClusterer  = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m', gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 14 });
                    
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer , 'clusterclick', function(cluster){
    //get all the markers in this cluster
    /var m = cluster.getMarkers(); 
    //get the position of one of them -- I picked the first one
    var newCenter = m[0].position; 
    //set the center to that one marker in the cluster
    map.setCenter(newCenter); 
    //zoom into that marker with the less tight zoom value      
    this.map.setZoom(markerClusterer.getMaxZoom()+1); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to determine the maximum zoom you want, then write a custom `clusterclick` listener, which zooms to the cluster bounds, then if the zoom is greater than your desired minimum (say 18), change the map zoom to that minimum value:

```
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
  imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
  gridSize: 50,
  maxZoom: 15,
  zoomOnClick: false // turn off the default clusterclick behavior
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
  var bounds = cluster.getBounds();
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() > 18)
      map.setZoom(18);
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

resulting zoom after clicking on the cluster:
[image: screenshot of map after clicking on cluster]

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y74L0zeo/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("$(document).ready")

  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.69484947367398, -80.30684540632623), //40.445235,-80.00594
    zoom: 12
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getZoom());
  })
  var myPoints = [
    [40.67241473672653, -80.30913200196709],
    [40.67244572478815, -80.30880637497815]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < myPoints.length; i++) {
    var lat = parseFloat(myPoints[i][0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(myPoints[i][1]);
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var marker = createMarker(point, map);
  } //end for

  var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
    gridSize: 50,
    maxZoom: 15,
    zoomOnClick: false // turn off the default clusterclick behavior
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    var bounds = cluster.getBounds();
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      if (map.getZoom() > 18)
        map.setZoom(18);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}); 

function createMarker(point, map) {
  // Create the HTML text based on the values passed in from XML

  var icon = {
    path: "M168.3 499.2C116.1 435 0 279.4 0 192C0 85.96 85.96 0 192 0C298 0 384 85.96 384 192C384 279.4 267 435 215.7 499.2C203.4 514.5 180.6 514.5 168.3 499.2H168.3zM192 256C227.3 256 256 227.3 256 192C256 156.7 227.3 128 192 128C156.7 128 128 156.7 128 192C128 227.3 156.7 256 192 256z", //SVG path of awesomefont marker
    fillColor: '#BF3604', //color of the marker
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0.4,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    scale: 0.07, //size of the marker, careful! this scale also affects anchor and labelOrigin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(200, 510), //position of the icon, careful! this is affected by scale
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(205, 190) //position of the label, careful! this is affected by scale
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    // id: marker_id,
    position: point,
    map: map,
    icon: icon
  });
  markers.push(marker); //add this marker to an array of all markers
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MarkerClusterer example</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```